# caret icon is not changing properly once collapsing the data

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a collapsible div using jQuery. However its caret icon is not changing properly.

When I click on it the first time it's changing, but when I a click second time it's not working properly. How can I solve this?

```js
$('.collapsible-heading').click(function() {
  $(this).next('.collapsible-content').slideToggle();
  // $('i').toggleClass("fa-caret-down")
  
  if ($('.collapsible-content').is(':visible')) {
    alert('asdasd')
    $('i').addClass('fa-caret-down').removeClass('fa-caret-left');
  } else if ($('.collapsible-content').is(':hidden')) {
    alert('asdasd')
    $('i').addClass('fa-caret-left').removeClass('fa-caret-down');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="collapsible-heading">
  <b>My heading</b> 
  <i class="fa fa-caret-left"></i>
</div>
<div class="collapsible-content" style="display: none;">
  my collapsible content
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because you're detecting the `:visible` state of the element after the animation has started. You need to reorganise the logic so that you check the state first, then call `slideToggle()`.

```js
$('.collapsible-heading').click(function() {  
  if ($('.collapsible-content').is(':visible')) {
    $('i').addClass('fa-caret-left').removeClass('fa-caret-down');
  } else if ($('.collapsible-content').is(':hidden')) {
    $('i').addClass('fa-caret-down').removeClass('fa-caret-left');
  }
  
  $(this).next('.collapsible-content').slideToggle();
});
```

However, it's worth noting that you can simplify the logic by removing the `:visible` check and just using `toggleClass()`:

```js
$('.collapsible-heading').click(function() {  
  $('i').toggleClass('fa-caret-left fa-caret-down');  
  $(this).next('.collapsible-content').slideToggle();
});
```

```css
.collapsible-content { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="collapsible-heading">
  <b>My heading</b> 
  <i class="fa fa-caret-left"></i>
</div>
<div class="collapsible-content">
  my collapsible content
</div>
```

Comment: No problem, glad to help